# Random arithmetic formulas

Tags: nt.number-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics

An *arithmetic formula* is a well-formed expression involving only the constant 1, and the binary operations of addition and multiplication, with multiplication by 1 not allowed. For instance, $1 + (1 + 1) \times ((1 + 1) + 1)$ is an arithmetic formula. Two quantities are are associated to each arithmetic formula: its *value* which is just the number obtained when the operations are performed (in the previous example, the value is $7$), and its *complexity* which is the number of $1$'s appearing in the expression (in the previous example, the complexity is $6$).

The minimal complexity $c(n)$ of an arithmetic formula with value $n$ (also called *arithmetic complexity of $n$*) has been popularized in [1]. It is not difficult to prove that $$\frac{3}{\log 3} \leq \frac{c(n)}{\log n} \leq \frac{3}{\log 2}, \quad n > 1$$ and slightly better bounds are known, but the precise behaviour of $c(n) / \log n$ is still a mystery (see, for example, [2]).

On the other hand, in [3] it is proved that the number $f(n)$ of arithmetic formulas with value $n$ satisfies $$f(n) \sim C \cdot \frac{\rho^n}{n^{3/2}}, \quad n \to +\infty$$ for some constants $C = 0.145\!\ldots$ and $\rho = 4.076\!\ldots$

Here come my question: **Can we obtain some (interesting) statistical results on arithmetic formulas involving both their complexities and their values?**

For example (in order of presumed difficulty):

- What is the asymptotic for the average value of an arithmetic formula of complexity $c$, as $c \to +\infty$ ?
- What is the asymptotic for the average complexity of an arithmetic formula of value $n$, as $n \to +\infty$ ?
- If $V_c$ is the random variable representing the value of a random arithmetic formula of complexity $c$, picked with uniform distribution, does some normalization of $V_c$ approach a continuous distribution?
- If $C_n$ is the random variable representing the complexity of a random arithmetic formula of value $n$, picked with uniform distribution, does some normalization of $C_n$ approach a continuous distribution?

Thank you for any suggestion/reference.

[1] R. K. Guy, *Some Suspiciously Simple Sequences*, The American Mathematical Monthly, 93 (1986), 186-190.

[2] H. Altman, *Integer complexity and well-ordering*, Michigan Mathematical Journal, 64 (2015), 509-538.

[3] E. K. Gnang, M. Radziwiłł, C. Sanna, *Counting arithmetic formulas*, European Journal of Combinatorics, 47 (2015) 40-53.

Comment: The second point needs refinement, as 1=1*1=1*1*1=1*1*1*1=...   You may need to talk about a weighted distribution of the set having value n.  Gerhard "Such As A Finite Cutoff" Paseman, 2017.09.14.

Comment: For the third point, a complexity c formula has a value at most 3^(c/3) or something near that, while the second largest is 8/9 of that at best, and the third largest less than an absolute fraction of the second.  How do you handle these outliers in a continuous fashion?  Gerhard "Wants To Learn Distributional Thinking" Paseman, 2017.09.14.

Comment: @Gerhard: OP prohibits multiplication by 1 (and there were no edits)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I don't get what you're saying about $V_c$. Of course the discribution of $V_c$ is discrete, but maybe some normalization of $V_c$ (like $V_c / 2^c$ or similar) tends to a continuous distribution as $c \to +\infty$.

Comment: Sorry about missing the restriction on multiplication: it changes some ideas I had about using expected values.  For the third point, look at the set S_8 of values involving complexity 8. It has 27 as its largest value, and the next largest is 24 followed by 18.  I think these ratios persist for all complexities larger than 8 among the largest values.  How are you smoothing things to work these values into a continuous distribution of values?  Gerhard "One Is The Loneliest Multiplicand" Paseman, 2017.09.14.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman OK, got it. "how" is part of the question.